# Karma unit tests for deferred promise in jsonp callback (stripe.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp, karma-runner, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe to get the user's credit card information, Stripe has a function which will make a JSONP request to generate a token (https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js)

I wrap this call inside a service:

```
app.factory('payment', ['$window', '$q', function($window, $q) {

  return {
    /**
     * Creates stripe token. This token will be send to our server.
     * @see https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms
     * @param  {Object} formData
     * @param  {Element} form
     * @return {Promise}
     */
    createStripeToken: function(formData, form) {
      if (angular.isUndefined($window.Stripe)) { return; }

      var deferred = $q.defer();

      Stripe.card.createToken(formData, function(status, response) {
        console.log(status) // => no output in test
        var error = response.error;

        if(error) {
          // use form to set validations
          if(error.type === 'card_error') {
            var formField = error.param; // 'cvc'
            form[formField].$setValidity(error.code, false);
          }
          deferred.reject();
        } else {
          // response contains id (token) and card, which contains additional card details
          deferred.resolve(response);
        }
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };

}]);
```

Everything is working fine, except the tests, here I am using Stripe with our TEST API key!

```
describe('Payment Service', function () {
  var service;
  var success, error;

  beforeEach(inject(function (payment) {
    service = payment;
  }));

  it('should get successful stripe response', function() {
    var createTokenFn = spyOn(Stripe.card, 'createToken');
    // Stripe.card.createToken = jasmine.createSpy("createToken");

    var formData = {
      number: '4111 1111 1111 1111',
      cvc: '123',
      exp_month: '12',
      exp_year: '23'
    };

    service.createStripeToken(formData, null).then(function(data) {
      console.log('success') // => no output
      success = data;
    }, function(data) {
      console.log('error') // => no output
      error = data;
    });

    $rootScope.$digest(); // $rootScope is loaded in my spec helper, this line makes no difference

    expect(createTokenFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(formData, jasmine.any(Function)); // success
    expect(success).not.toEqual(undefined); // fail
  });

});
```

Is this the right way to test a service like this? And how can I test that the callback works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get your hands on the callback by using [`callFake`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callFake%3C/code%3E) provided by the spy.

```
var createTokenFn = spyOn(Stripe.card, 'createToken').andCallFake(function(formData, callback) {
    callback(200, { error: undefined });
});
```

You can then modify the answer to fit in your different use cases.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bbbuu37w/1/

Don't know if it is any use for you but I came across that [lib](https://github.com/Venturocket/angular-stripe-js) which seems to be a wrapper to Strip.Js for angular.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works :) do you know how to not stub the response, but get the actual response?

I know that there are many different wrappers and modules for stripe.js but they all do things differently and some are not tested, so I made my own approach.

Comment: Suppose that the callback mean some async processing say http call from the lib so you would need to hook into it to mock the part you need. The response object seems well enough documented though and probably maintained so I would rely on that. Otherwise actual response could mean actual call so some integration test with the actual service could come handy. But I tend to write facades or some sort of wrapper to this kind of library to test my code behavior instead of third party one for unit testing.